# CSS styling conflicts with jquery hide mechanism

Tags: jquery, css

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // apply event handler to radio inputs
    $('.field-name-main input').change(function() {
      // if 1 or more YES selections are found
      if ($('.field-name-main input:checked').length > 0) {
        // hide submit button
        $('#edit-field-radio-list-wrapper').hide();
      }
      // otherwise
      else {
        // show submit button
        $('#edit-field-radio-list-wrapper').show();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.radio-list-item-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 1em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-name-field-radio-list-value field-widget-options-buttons form-wrapper" id="edit-field-radio-list-wrapper">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-field-radio-value-und">
    <label for="eedit-field-radio-list-wrapper">Value </label>

    <div class="form-item form-type-radio radio-list-item-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id=" edit-field-value-1" name="radio-list-item" value="164" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for=" edit-field-value-1">1 </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio radio-list-item-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id=" edit-field-value-2" name="radio-list-item" value="165" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for=" edit-field-value-2">2 </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio radio-list-item-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id=" edit-field-value-3" name="radio-list-item" value="166" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for=" edit-field-value-3">3 </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio radio-list-item-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="edit-field-value-4" name="radio-list-item" value="168" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for=" edit-field-value-4">4 </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio radio-list-item-wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id=" edit-field-value-5" name="radio-list-item" value="167" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for=" edit-field-value-5">5 </label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-name-main field-widget-options-buttons form-wrapper" id="edit-main ">
    <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-field-main-und">
      <label for="edit-main">This is the main field </label>
      <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-main-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-main-und-135" name="field_main[und]" value="135" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for="edit-field-main-und-135">option 1 </label>

      </div>
      <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-main-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-main-und-717" name="field_main[und]" value="717" class="form-radio" /> <label class="option" for="edit-field-main-und-717">option 2 </label>

      </div>
```

I have some jquery set up to hide a radio list field when the user clicks on an adjacent field. I'm trying to style the radio list to display horizontally, but it breaks the jquery. The list itself is Drupal reference generated, so radio items are defined as div, not li.

The working jquery looks like this:

```
      // apply event handler to radio inputs
      $('.main-field input').change(function(){
        // if 1 or more YES selections are found
        if($('.main-field input:checked').length > 0){
          // hide submit button
          $('.radio-list-field').hide();
        }
        // otherwise
        else{
          // show submit button
          $('.radio-list-field').show();
        }
      });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

The css portion to style the radio list currently includes this:

```
.radio-list-item-wrapper {
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have tried using flex instead of inline, but that doesn't work either. Float:left also breaks the jquery. None of the other attributes affect functionality.

Is there a different approach that gets me the horizontal display I want without breaking the jquery code?

Comment: You'll need to show your HTML. Don't make us guess. Put all your code in a functioning snippet using the editor.

Comment: You could try changing `.show()` / `.hide()` to `.css("display", "none")` and `.css("display", "inline")` as jquery will change to `block` for `.show`

Comment: @freedomn-m Actually, jQuery attempts to get the default `display` value: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/css/showHide.js#L7

Comment: Sorry about that @isherwood. Stackoverflow newbie here. Will post snippet shortly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Does that suggest this is actually a Drupal issue? Should I be looking at writing a hook to bypass that default in this instance instead of trying to fix it via CSS? Or is there something I can add to my jquery code to do that for me?

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "breaks the jQuery". It's quite difficult to "break" jQuery itself. I would suggest rewriting your code to be one line: `$(".radio-list-field").toggle(this.checked)`. Note that will toggle the appearance of all elements with that class based on the one checkbox. Not sure if that is intended or not.

Comment: Thanks, @HereticMonkey, I changed the language to say "conflicts with" instead. The intent is to hide the dependent field when ANY option is checked in the main list. I'm using the value field to filter the main list, but once the user selects an item, I want the value list to go away. This prevents them from trying to refilter the list without clearing it first.

Comment: Snippet has been added. Oddly, the functionality is working fine here, but still fails on the live site. It's definitely the :display: inline/inline-block/flex" or "float: left"  part that's interfering.

Comment: On further investigation, it looks like the dependency module is causing the conflict - the issue only occurs after I change the value and trigger the main field change. It's dropping the "ajax-processed" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use CSS "opacity" property with value "0/1" to show/hide the UI
Which will not break the jquery code and perform css operations easily

Comment: Opacity will not cause the item to collapse when hidden; the item will take the same amount of room as it did previously, unlike with `display: none`